# Draw UIBezierPath on UIImageView

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiimageview, uibezierpath

How can i draw `UIBezierPath` on `UIImageView`? I have tried following code but when `UIImageView's` image is `nil` then I am only able to see the path, when I add the image this path is overlapped with the `UIImageView's` image. I want to draw the path above the `UIImageVIew's` image.

Comment: The image might be overwriting the context. Maybe have two imageviews? One for the image, and another on top for the line?

Comment: You didn't provide any reference to the code you had tried. Anyway - UIImageView is a beast of it's own (it will not call drawRect for example). You could for example add UIImageView to a UIView and another transparent UIVIew on top of it and draw the UIBezier path to the last one.

Answer (score 5):

Yes you can draw bezierpaths in uiimageview by clling a draw method like DrawRect in uiview.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a transparent `UIView` on top of your `UIImageView`.
Make a UIView subclass for this transparent view.
Override `drawRect` method in this subclass.
`stroke` all the paths you want to draw.

Please get back to me if you want sample code for this.